# Delete partial matching lines from text file

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

I have 1 large xml file with lines like -

```
<text file name 5 HD text>
<text file name 2 text>
<text file name 3 text>
<text file name HD 2 text>
<text file name 5 text>
```

Is possible using vbscript or powershell to output -

```
<text file name 5 HD text>
<text file name 3 text>
<text file name HD 2 text>
```

and in new file add lines being deleted -

```
<text file name 2 text>
<text file name 5 text>
```

`HD` is anywhere in file name and no sorting.

I find [Deleting entire lines in a text file based on a partial string match with Windows PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/117650/deleting-entire-lines-in-a-text-file-based-on-a-partial-string-match-with-window) but is not exact answer. No Java per favore as I remove this for hacking safety.

Comment: What's the rule for what goes into each file?  It's not every other nor is lines containing "HD", nor is it odd versus even numbers.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: Sorry please I no understand what you say. Some file names are there 2 times, 1 normal and 1 HD version. I want to remove normal version line to new file if HD version is there. If no HD then normal version is remaining in original xml.

Answer (score 0):

Simple script to separate lines into different files based on arbitrary criteria (such as if HD tag is there)

```
# Get the contents of the file.
$file = get-content ~\file.xml

# Loop through the xml file adding all "HD" tags to one file and all non "HD" tags to another file
foreach($text in $file)
{
    if($text.Contains("HD")) {
        Add-Content ~\hd.txt $text
    } 
    else {
        Add-Content ~\nohd.txt $text
    }
}
```

If the criteria is a little different, then just change the "if" statement to suit your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for program, but is vbscript? powershell? Please help how to run? I think program will put HD file lines and normal file lines in 2 different files? but I want xml to have final list with HD if is there, and normal if no HD is there. new file must have only file lines deleted from xml.

Comment: Sorry @Angelo, this is PowerShell. You're right about the script placing things in two different files. Do you mean you want the current XML to keep the HD files? And then a separate file with Deleted Code? If so, please see my edit

Comment: No sorry please, is ok. I explain to nicole above - some files are having normal and HD version, some are only normal no HD. If 2 version, I want only HD in xml and normal in new file. If 1 version only - normal or HD - I want in xml like before.